# Error: File not found

Tags: boot-failure

Error: File not found.
Press any key to continue...--

I get this when after I choose Ubuntu on start. Pressing any key doesn't work. What's this? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: This means that the grub-bootloader is corrupted. Follow the answer below to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few people have experienced this after upgrading from 12.04 to 13.04 ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/733836)).

A way of fixing this without messing around with live CD/USB stick is to work out which is your boot disk.  Running `df`. Most often it is `/dev/sda`

**Do not use the version with the number on the end, eg /dev/sda1**

Once you have established the boot disk you then reinstall grub (the boot loader) by running:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # replace X with your actual value
sudo update-grub
```

(Source is [this comment on the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/733836/comments/11)).

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing start up problems using boot-repair

1. Boot into the Ubuntu Live Disk (This is so that we have an Ubuntu session to run the repair tools, not to reinstall)
2. Open up a Terminal window (Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
3. Run the following in the Terminal:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

   `boot-repair`
4. Once in the program, just click on the "Recommended repair" option.  After that has completed, click OK and restart your computer without the Live Disk connected to the computer.

You computer should now boot properly into Ubuntu.  If it does not, do the steps again but look through the options in the Advanced menu in boot-repair.