# Error: File not found without any grub menu

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu on the third partition and removed my Ubuntu partition, which was the second one before. Unlike [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202313/error-file-not-found), I am not seeing any grub menus before shall I do the same?

I just installed Kubuntu and got this wonderfull message during the first startup

```bash
error: File not found
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Is boot repair also working with Kubuntu 12.10

Comment: dear Anton. You are sounding a bit horrified, so that I'll help you I'd suggest you to start the live usb again and back up your data on any stick or Cd, then try boot-repair, if this doesn't work either I'd open Gparted and delete all partitions on your Hdd. Afterwards I'd make a large Ntfs partition and install Windows again on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this application named Boot-repair
[Boot-Repair - how to use](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

1 Boot Ubuntu from a Live USB

2 Connect to the internet

3 Open a terminal, and add the Boot Repair PPA

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

4 Install Boot Repair

```
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```